# Reading angular data before its bound html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have span tags that I get the contents of using a function, but before the HTML is updated with the angular scope variable, the function grabs the string "{{projects.title}}" I have tried using ng-cloak, and ng-bind, but neither achieve the expected effect

Ex.1

```
<pre id='typewriter'>
  <span>A NOODLE</span>
  <span>HOUSE</span>
</pre>
```

Ex. 2

```
<pre id='typewriter'>
  <span>{{project.title}}</span>
  <span>{{project.name}}</span>
</pre>
```

The text content is evaluated as A NOODLE HOUSE in the first example, but {{project.title}} in the second example

```
var typer = document.getElementById('typewriter');
var HTML = typer.textContent;
```

How do I get the textContent to be the data bound to project.title and project.name?

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? Why do you need the text content?

Comment: The text content is written out letter by letter, a typewriter effect. A new project name and title appears every 4 seconds

Comment: Sounds like something you should be doing with an Angular directive. Check out this one ~ https://github.com/qqnc/angular-typewriter